# PHP get link to Facebook post

Tags: php, facebook

I **successfully** post something to a Facebook group using:

```
$post_url = '/' . $my_group_id . '/feed';
$msg_body = array('link' => urldecode($link), 'message' => 'New post:');
try {
  $postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body);
  if (!$postResult) // handle error...
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  // handle error...
}
```

Question is: How can I get the permanent link to this new post in Facebook, so I can point to it from another website?

I can get it **manually** by checking the properties of the new post in Facebook, but how can I get it **within the PHP code**, after the successful posting above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this response in your `$postResult`:

```
{
  "id": "xxxx_xxxx"
}
```

The permalink would be `"https://facebook.com/{id}"`, so it's:

```
https://facebook.com/xxxx_xxxx
```

Facebook will handle the forwarding to the real final url in your group.

I tested this using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and it seems to work consistently.

Comment: This WORKS!!
I simply checked and then used $postResult['id']

Comment: An even better solution (that works even when you're not logged-in to Facebook) is: http://www.facebook.com/groups/xxxx/permalink/xxxx/